# what does the ! mean in Angular? i.e $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering what does the ! actually mean in this method

```
 $scope.toggleSelected = function () {
      $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
```

I understand it's allowing me to set a selected item and it won't work without it  but what exactly is the ! for?

Comment: Do you know what `toggle` means? This is what `!` is for, toggling between `true` and `false`.

Comment: it mean, as in many other langage, the opposite of a boolean expression. !true => false.

Comment: [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29)

Comment: you should read about basic operator, like '&' , '|' , '&&', '||' , '!' , '++' ...

Comment: Called Logical NOT Operator. It is used to reverse the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true, then Logical NOT operator will make it false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` is the normal negation operator.

Inside of that function, it's used to flip/toggle the value each time it's called. For example, from `true` to `false` and vice-versa.